# How to pass/access variables used inside objective function in scipy differential evolution

Tags: python, function, variables, optimization, scipy

I'm using DE to optimize a Neural Network problem. And i need to access variables inside the object function to create a plot.

I report here a simple example without NN just to better explain my problem.

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

def obj_fun(x):
    A= x[0]
    B= x[1]
    C= A*B+B**3
return C

solution=differential_evolution(obj_fun,
                            bounds=[(10,20),(5,15)],
                            strategy='rand1exp',
                            popsize=10,
                            maxiter=20,
                            polish=True,
                            disp=True,
                            seed=0)
```

I'd like to know how I can create a DataFrame containing all the A and B tried by DE so i can make a 3D plot to visualize the best couples A,B that provides better C.

I think that solution would be something that allows variables used inside the objective function to be "extracted" out of it at every run to create a DF using append method. But I really don't know how to do that.

I'll really appreciate anyone help on that.
Thank you

Steve.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code?

Comment: Sure, i've just edited the main question.

Comment: Please correct indentation. Honestly, I don't know what your question is. Also your code doesn't seem to be reproducible as explained in the link above.

Comment: I've indented as requested. My code is not reproducible cause i made a lot of cut to paste here. What i'm doing is optimizig parameters of a neural network with DE. I'd like to create a dataframe that stores a row with x[0],x[1] values for every attempt made by DE so that i can use those data to create a 3D plot that shows visually which pair of n°neurons and time steps (lag) gives the best MAE. My problem in short is that i don't know how to "see" or "extract" or "work" with variables inside the object function. Their kinda of temporary and doesn not show up in Spyder Variable Explorer.

Comment: If i could "see" those variables like in a script i could easily use append to create a the DF I need, but since they're inside the objective function i cannot. Forgive me if i'm not clear, i have difficulties in expressing in english.

Comment: Try making your code minimal and reproducible. If you want to get answer on some mechanism, then make minimal example that shows this mechanism. Do you want a function that remembers some internal values and they can be accessed? Then make your code with DE etc. And make it minimal. I have no idea what Keras LSTM is, so I'm off topic in the first sentence.

Comment: Ok i'll write another example tomorrow. Thank you for your time and patience. I Really appreciated it.

Comment: @rpoleski. Done, let me know if it's clearer now :)

Comment: Ok, now I'm able to parse. You have my answer below. More elegant way would be to use class for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def obj_fun(x):
    A= x[0]
    B= x[1]
    C= A*B+B**3
    obj_fun.dump.append([A, B, C])
return C
obj_fun.dump = []
```

and then access `obj_fun.dump` after DE run.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i needed!